# Add dynamically Autocomplete Material UI field in React

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm currently working on a ReactJs app and I'm having a problem adding input fields dynamically.
When it comes to a simple input field, everything works (even adding and removing fields).

The problem occurs with the Autocomplete field of Material UI. The logic works, but nothing registers in the right place in state. Either it doesn't register at all or it causes me to crash the app.

This is an default input field with her function for change state:

```
 <FormControl className="form-item-two">
          <InputLabel>
              Quantity
            </InputLabel>
            <Input
              id="order-detail-quantity"
              className="input-form"
              type="text"
              name="productQuantity"
              value={item.productQuantity}
              onChange={e => handleChange(e, i)}
            />
   </FormControl>



const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target;

    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = value;

    setInputList(list);
  }
```

Now this is my Autocomplete field with her function for change state:

```
<FormControl className="form-item-one">
            <Autocomplete
              className="input-form"
              id="product"
              options={data}
              autoHighlight
              onChange={handleProductInputChange}
              getOptionLabel={(item) => item.ref}
              renderOption={(item) => (
                <React.Fragment>
                  {item.ref} {item.produit}
                </React.Fragment>
              )}
              
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  label="Choose a product"
                  variant="outlined"
                  inputProps={{
                    ...params.inputProps,
                    autoComplete: "new-password", // disable autocomplete and autofill
                  }}
                />
              )}
            />
          </FormControl>

  const handleProductInputChange = (values, i) => {

    // Do something
  };
```

And this is my default state:

```
const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([
    {
      productDetails: {
        productRef: "",
        productName: "",
        productDimension: "",
        productIndicationOne: "",
        productIndicationTwo: "",
        productIndicationThree: "",
        productIndicationFour: "",
        productIndicationFive: "",
        productIndicationSix: "",
        productIndicationSeven: "",
        productIndicationEight: "",
        productIndicationNine: "",
        productIndicationTen: "",
        productIndicationEleven: "",
      },
      productQuantity: 10,
      productTotalPrice: 100,
  },

  ]);
```

Do you have an idea ?

thank you in advance

Comment: Anybody can help me please ?

Comment: I don’t see anywhere a name prop on the auto complete nor the textfield. Since your states depends on this, this might be why.